# How to send web request using proxy server for particular connection for c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, proxy, httpwebrequest

I want to send web request using proxy sever i found from searching and applied below code but don't work.

`HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlid);`

```
                 WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("186.192.17.138", 8080);
                myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
                request.Proxy = myproxy;
            request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

`request.Method = "POST";`

Above code gives an error of "**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.**"

When i set system proxy settings and try to request using my application without requesting through proxy then also it is giving the same error as above.

I can't understand what is the actual problem?